# Multiple Angular Filters for ng-repeat - Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently working on a car rental site which I'm building with angular.

In the car selection section the user needs to be able to filter on a lot of different properties, such as 4x4, Automatic or Manual gear, and the categories of the cars, like compact, premium, sports car etc. On top of that there needs to be some pretty extensive work on ordering the cars as well.

This was easy to achieve by the standard filters and a small directive for each filter-button, but I can imagine how long the ng-repeat attribute is going to be with like 12 filters. Probably nothing I should be afraid of, but still.

**What I wanted to run by you guys is if there is a better solution than this.**

This is bound to be unnecessarily messy in the end.

This is how it's running now:

Html:

```
    <div filter-btn="4x4" ng-model="filters" class="btn">4x4</div>
    <div filter-btn="manual" ng-model="filters" class="btn">manual</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filters.searchCar">
    <div class="car-cont">
        <div ng-repeat="car in filteredCars = (cars | filter:filters.4x4 | filter:filters.manual | filter:filters.searchCar)" class="car">{{car.model}}</div>
        <div ng-show="!filteredCars.length">No cars</div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('mabi').directive('filterBtn',[ function () {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, elem, attr){
        var activeFilter = attr.filterBtn;

        var clickFunction = function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                if (scope.model[activeFilter] != activeFilter){
                    scope.model[activeFilter] = activeFilter;
                } else {
                    scope.model[activeFilter] = "";
                }
            });
            console.log(scope.model);
        }

        elem.bind('click', clickFunction);
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkFunction,
        scope: {
            model: "=ngModel"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern, but I would say that the first thing you should do is try it out.  Make a test with as much data as you could ever reasonably expect and try all the filters on a slow machine with a bad browser (cough! IE8... cough!).

If performance truly is unacceptable under those conditions, then you could try making a custom filter that takes parameters instead of chaining a bunch of filters.  I'm not sure if this would be faster, but it would at least eliminate a lot of individual function calls.  And it would also give you full control of optimizing the code.